# Best way to make separate Glue tables for each partition?

Tags: etl, aws-glue, amazon-athena, partition

I have some data in Glue that is partitioned by customer. This is used for internal analytics. However, eventually this data needs to be exposed to the customers themselves. Since Glue/Athena do not support partition-based access control, it seems like I will need to create separate tables for each customer.

I don't think there's a way in Glue to create a consolidated partitioned table, but ALSO created separate tables, but I could be wrong.

Do I need to write an ETL job to do this, using something like [predicate pushdowns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions-pushdowns), or is there a simpler way?

Comment: This is usually managed by your code to append to the WHERE statement and filter on the customer-id based on the customer that is accessing it. Is there a reason not to apply it here?

Comment: You can create multiple tables based on the path using a Glue Crawler. When in the conf it asks for s3 path, you put one for each partition that you have. In this way you will not need to touch the data.